# PHP | Make a validation check whether the number has a decimal point == x.00 or not

Tags: php

Em, I don't know how to explain this. I hope you'll get the point.

I've variables:

```php
$a = 10; //int
$b = 2.5; //float
$c = $a * $b; //I know this return will be float: 25
```

From those variables, I want to make a statement as follows:

```php
if (//the value of $c have a decimal point == x.00) {
    echo $c;
} else {
    echo '';
}
```

Did you get it? What I want is that when the decimal point of `$c` is x.00 (like 25.00, 10.00, etc), the `$c` will be printed. But if the decimal point is **NOT** x.00 (eg 25.50, 25.7, etc) then `$c` will **NOT** be printed.

I've read some references but still don't understand how to do it.

Thank you. I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: What about ( (int) $c == $c ) ?

Comment: Have a look at [is_float()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-float.php) and [round()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php).

Comment: Add all possibilities. What about `45`,`45.0`,`0.0`,`0.00`?

Comment: @Andreas Simple and work! I prefer your method. Thank you! I really love this community!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP has `is_integer()` - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-integer.php

Or if you want to check manually, then you can compare against the rounded down (floor) and rounded up (ceil) values:

```
if ($a==Floor($a) && $a==Ceil($a)){
 // Whole Number
} else {
 // Has decimal point value
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I was greatly helped :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try like below.

```
<?php
  function is_decimal_exist( $value ) {
     return is_numeric( $value ) && floor( $value ) != $value;
  }

   $my_value = "10.00";
      

   if( is_decimal_exist ( $my_value ) ) {
       echo ''; // Decimal Present, Do Not Print $my_value
   }else{
       echo $my_value; // Print $my_value
   }
?>
```

Comment: Welcome. I tried function so once included, it can be used multiple times across all pages without any extra coding...

Answer (score 0):

Much easier.  Just check if the integer of the number is equal `==` to the number:

```
if ((int)$c == $c) {
    echo $c;
} else {
    echo '';
}
```